# Fetch Multiple blobs in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

We are storing data in serialized form in Oracle tables. Column which holds the serialized data is of Type BLOB. We do have a stored procedure to query the table and return the results as sys_refcursor. The stored procedure accepts list of keys in comma separated form for which the blobs are to be fetched.

Environment - JRE 1.6
Oracle 11g

Problem : While the application requests the data for say 8 or 10 rows, we want the stored procedure to return all the result rows with binary data in a single db round trip. Is this possible? or what is the best way to fetch the results with minimal database round trip.

(We have set the fetchRowsize to 10, so that multiple rows are fetched. We have also Set the setLOBPrefetchSize to sufficient big value (3 Meg) . However these does not seem to make a difference. The resultSet.getBytes() takes a significant time indicating the data is fetched on request)

What am i missing? Do we have any trace to enable/check what is going on underneath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BLOB trigger intentionally some specific behaviour, since they can be extremely large (depends on block size, but maximum size is at least 8 TB). The drivers do not always know in advance how much data will be transferred, so the driver takes the safe route by default.

I understand that you want it in just one roundtrip to get over, probably because of your network latency? If not, please state.

We've had the same problem with a standard software package we develop and in which the client retrieves on connection setup a lot of data across the globe. We've solved it as follows:

1. Initially we used a stored procedure that takes a parameter with the hash value of the last retrieved data rows. Stored procedure checks hash of current data rows. If not different, it returns just a header. If different, it puts everything together in one large piece and sends that back. In that way, it avoids transferring lots of information across the globe, because high network latency often comes with low bandwidth. Plus the number of round trips is reduced.
2. The last two years we've inserted a different product of our company in between (a webservice provider). It does  the compression and deduplication by itself and further reduces bandwidth need. Plus it only uses SQL*Net between the webservice and the Oracle RDBMS. The webservice communicates using bson (json in binary format).

With a low labour effort, I would recommend returning just one LOB from the stored procedure with everything in it. Maybe even compressing it or taking use of a client's side cache.

Option 2 described above takes a lot more labour to introduce.

Comment: Latency is the primary concern. Our networks have a RTT of approximately 20-30 ms. In case where we are fetching multiple entities, this would make us hold the connection for a longer time (which we want to avoid). We are inclined towards option 1 but need more light on how to split the BLOBs back in the client code. (I see  we can use dbms_lob.Append function to append the LOB in server).

Comment: Do you use the individual LOB lengths to split? or any other better options?

Comment: In step 1 we separated using something similar to "first tell me how bytes follow, then the content". Similar to the String environment in many runtime environment (not C with trailing \0). In step 2 we are using wrapping (serializing) it using bson. So binary format of [ [ [ field 1 name ], [field 2 name] ], [ [PAYLOAD 1 ROW 1], [PAYLOAD 2 ROW 1] ], [ [PAYLOAD 3 of ROW 2], ...] ]

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use Oracle's thin JDBC driver, you might want to try setting the connection property `useFetchSizeWithLongColumn` to true, see in http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/905/jdbc-javadoc/index.html?oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html. However, as the property name indicates it is meant for LONG columns and it may not have any effect on BLOB columns. (Unfortunaetly, I am not able to try it myself here. However, source code under http://ora-jdbc-source.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/OracleJDBC/src/oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleResultSetImpl.java does not seem to make LONG/LOB distinction with useFetchSizeWithLongColumn, just "re-opens streams".)

For verification/tracing see the example code in: http://steveracanovic.blogspot.de/2009/08/using-usefetchsizewithlongcolumn-and.html

If the connection property does not work for BLOBs, you might try returning LONGs. However, there does not seem to be a nice method of conversion from BLOBs to LONGs. The following discussion (see answers) mentions a way using RAW variables in PL/SQL: http://oracle.mscer.com/q_oracle_41102.html. As you use mentioned using a stored procedure, you might want to try this.

(Note that setting the connection property implies that prefetched LONG data may consume considerable amounts of memory.)

(Again, I'm sorry I cannot try this approach myself and cannot assist with details as I do not have an Oracle DB here. But as nobody came up with an answer during past two hours ...)